# phonegap splash screen is black in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am having difficulty getting the splash screen to show up for Android through PhoneGap Build. Here is the reference code in my config.xml, only show the black screen when I open an android application, please help to solve this problem,
below is my config.xml, I refer more sites those are given codes inserted in below config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.projectid" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Project name</name>
    <description>
        Project application
    </description>
    <author email="info@Project.com" href="http://Project.com">
        Project
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />


    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />

    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>

    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />

    <platform name="android">        
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
        <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
        <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
        <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```